# uefi/gpt install grub on several external usb disk

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

- My computer uses UEFI
- I have several external USB disks, each with a GPT partition table, a small partition flagged 'bios-grub', and each has an Ubuntu 22.04 installed on an other partition.

My purpose is to be able to boot on each of them just by switching the usb wire.

Following many posts find here and there (typically people with a Windows dual boot--which is not my case), I'm using the following commands:

```
os_partition=/dev/sdcXXX   <-- the one with the Ubuntu
sudo mount $os_partition /ubuntu
sudo mount --bind /dev /ubuntu/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /ubuntu/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /ubuntu/sys
```

And then I try many combinations of the following:

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/ubuntu /dev/sdc
sudo update-grub
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

My current problem is:

- power off the computer
- I plug one USB drive,
- power on the computer
- select "boot on USB"
- all work perfectly: grub shows up, select Ubuntu, all ok.

Same steps with an other USB drive:

```
error: no such device: <UUID of the OTHER usb drive, the one not plugged in>
error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode
```

**Question**: how do I tell my bios/uefi where to search for grub ?

I guess that, on my 'bios-grub' partition, something is pointing to the wrong partition ... (?)

Comment: Your 'bios-grub' IS the wrong partition... Meaning: Your using Legacy installation in a UEFI machine, why?

Comment: @ChanganAuto: I've read at several place that I need a small "bios-gub" partition as first partition of my disk. But I can have misunderstood. What should I do instead ?

Comment: You need it if you intend to do a Legacy installation in GPT drives and in that case ONLY. It "simulates" the MBR that doesn't exist in GPT, obviously, but is expected for Legacy/"BIOS" in order to install the bootloader (Grub). A proper UEFI mode installation use a small FAT32 partition (ESP - EFI System Partition).

Comment: ok, so I change my "bios-grub" partition into a FAT32 one. The do I have to flag it in some sense ? How do I say "if you see this disk, you have to search for the grub files on THIS disk, that partition" ?

Comment: It's not that simple. First of all size matters. The typical `bios_grub` unformatted partition is only 1 or 2MB. The typical ESP created by Windows is 100MB (the Ubuntu installer creates a 512MB one). Flags are only for Windows. For Ubuntu you'd need to install the EFI Grub instead. The best way is to (1) remove or disable any internal drive and (2) boot Ubuntu installation media in the proper UEFI mode and install (or re-install without formatting the root file system). Otherwise, perhaps more complicated - counter-intuitively - is to use Boot Repair.

Comment: @ChanganAuto When you say "re-install", you mean re-install grub is suppose ? Not the whole filesystem ?

Comment: If you have a proper EFI partition sure, you can go that route.

Comment: Thanks I will try when I'm back home.